# Add function to every post?

Tags: functions, hooks

I have some code that generates a dropdown list of all my `post` files.  I would like to add this dropdown to the top of every post page, right before the post content.

What's the correct hook/action to do so?

custom-functions.php:

```
<?php
function create_post_dropdown($titles){
    ?>
    <div id="article-choice">
    <h3>Choose an Article, or browse below</h3>
    <select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
        <?php 
        foreach($titles as $title => $url){
            echo "<option value=" . $url . ">" . $title . "</option>";
        } 
        ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('__after_header', 'create_post_dropdown');
function add_dropdown_to_posts(){
    $args = [
             'post_type' => 'post',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'posts_per_page' => -1
        ];
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    $titles = get_post_titles($args);
    if (get_post_type() == "post"){
        $title = $post->post_title; // get_the_title();
        $title = create_post_dropdown($titles) . "<br>" . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_dropdown_to_posts');
```

The idea is that when a `post` page is opened/viewed, this dropdown (made via `create_post_dropdown`) will be added before the post content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to have the custom dropdown function `return` the custom html. Then you can call it inside your `add_dropdown_to_posts` and put the returned content into a helper variable. After that just prepend the custom html to the `$content` variable that the [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter provides.

Like this,

```
function my_custom_dropdown_html() {
 return '<html stuff here>'; // you could put your html also in a variable and then return that.
}
function add_dropdown_html_before_the_content($content) {
 $dropdown = my_custom_dropdown_html();
 // if statement just to be safe - e.g you change the custom function output to something else than string of html and forget you've used it here
 if ( $dropdown && is_string( $dropdown ) ) {
  $content = $dropdown . $content; // prepend custom html to content
 }
 return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_dropdown_html_before_the_content' );
```

Comment: Aha! That's so much simpler than what I was trying, and easy to follow and implement.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems to put the dropdown in between the page Header (with the article title, author, etc.) and the content (which makes sense, we're using `the_content` hook).  How could I put it just before the Header HTML? There's no `the_header` hook that I could find.

Comment: I guess it depends on the theme that you're using. If it's some theme from the WP theme repository or a premium theme, then it might provide some custom hooks, which you could use just like the `the_content` hook. But you need to look at the theme's code to see if there's any hooks available. Or if the page header is a template part, you could copy the part into a matching folder (e.g. /partials) in your child theme and modify it to your liking. And if it's a theme that you're building yourself then you could toss in a custom `do_action` to your page header file and then use that one.